# Eclipse keyboard shortcut for passing a parameter to a method

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I was watching a video and I saw the tutor doing a correction in his code in `Eclipse` without touching the mouse. Below is the code.

```
    System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(ch)'c');
```

He changed the code to :

```
   System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('c'));
```

I have always wanted to do this because it is a pain to do it using backspaces and retype the ')' at the end.
Does anyone know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: It's possible that the solution is in Preferences > General > Keys

Comment: Is this video available to the public? Could you post a link?

Comment: Nopes. The video is not available to the public. :(

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> on the editor will take you to the first problem (error / warning). In your case, it will highlight *ch*, next you press **delete twice** to delete *ch* and *)*. Then you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to position at the right place for inserting bracket and then press **)**. All these will get to what you want without using mouse.